# String num1= stdin.readLineSync(); not allowing me to enter a number, answer shows "null"

Tags: flutter, debugging, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-test

I'm trying to get user input using the  "stdin.readLineSync();" code but it doesn't wait for me to input a number. It just shows "null".
This is the full code;

```
void main(){

  print("Enter first number");

  String num1= stdin.readLineSync();

  print(num1);

}
```

---

On the debug console it shows;

```
flutter: Enter first number

flutter: null
```

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: don't use stdin with flutter project

Comment: What do I use to get user input?

Comment: Use TextField Widget

Answer (score 1):

void main(){

print("Enter first number");

String num1= stdin.readLineSync()!;

print(num1);

}
**change**  stdin.readLineSync();

---

**To** stdin.readLineSync()!;

**Null Check(!)**